# GET TOP HIT FROM A VALUE IF THIS IS 0 KIBANA

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

My first post, I spend the weekend looking for an answer without a good result

I will try to explain my issue, I have this Index

ST    ID
0     1
1     1
 
0     2
 
1     2 
 
0     2
 
1     3
 
0     3

For example, I need to show the last records from each ID when them are 0, for example, in this index I have to show only ID 1 and ID 2, becuase the last record has ST to 0 in ID 1 and 2

Could some try to help me with this issue?

BR

Comment: Is there a unique date field in these? and as per data  in question values will be 2 and 3 , correct?

Comment: Hi J, ID is unique and could be 1,2,3,4. I only need to know from these IDs the last doc only if it is 0, in that example only ID 1 and ID 2 are OK to be shown, ID 3 the last record has ST at 1, and it doesn't to be show, in SQL maybe i could get them with group by and having, value ST is only 0 or 1

Comment: json data is not ordered. Is there any field like date which can be used to define an order

Comment: Yes it is, there is the timestamp field, perfect to do this :D

Comment: I get almost what i want but, how can I apply it in KIBANA? I need to show a table with ID with their top hit when ST is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapping:

```
PUT index34
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "ST":{
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "ID":{
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "Date":{
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Data:

```
[
      {
        "_index" : "index34",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "LO7Z7W0B_-hMjUaqtwHw",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "ST" : 1,
          "ID" : 1,
          "Date" : "2019-10-21T12:00:00Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index34",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Le7Z7W0B_-hMjUaq0QEz",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "ST" : 0,
          "ID" : 1,
          "Date" : "2019-10-21T12:01:00Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index34",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Lu7a7W0B_-hMjUaqAwE0",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "ST" : 1,
          "ID" : 2,
          "Date" : "2019-10-21T12:02:00Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index34",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "L-7a7W0B_-hMjUaqGAEr",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "ST" : 0,
          "ID" : 2,
          "Date" : "2019-10-21T12:04:00Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index34",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "MO7a7W0B_-hMjUaqNAGA",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "ST" : 0,
          "ID" : 3,
          "Date" : "2019-10-21T12:04:00Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index34",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Me7a7W0B_-hMjUaqTQFP",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "ST" : 1,
          "ID" : 3,
          "Date" : "2019-10-21T12:06:00Z"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Query:  I am getting max date for all terms and then getting the max value when ST was zero. If these two match(which means 0 was latest document) then I am keeping tha bucket

```
GET index34/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "ID": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ID",
        "size": 10000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "maxDate": {
          "max": {
            "field": "Date"
          }
        },
        "pending_status": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "ST": 0
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "filtered_maxdate": {
              "max": {
                "field": "Date"   
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "buckets_latest_status_pending": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "filtereddate": "pending_status>filtered_maxdate",
              "maxDate": "maxDate"
            },
            "script": "params.filtereddate==params.maxDate"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "ID" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 1,
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "pending_status" : {
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "filtered_maxdate" : {
              "value" : 1.57165926E12,
              "value_as_string" : "2019-10-21T12:01:00.000Z"
            }
          },
          "maxDate" : {
            "value" : 1.57165926E12,
            "value_as_string" : "2019-10-21T12:01:00.000Z"
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : 2,
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "pending_status" : {
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "filtered_maxdate" : {
              "value" : 1.57165944E12,
              "value_as_string" : "2019-10-21T12:04:00.000Z"
            }
          },
          "maxDate" : {
            "value" : 1.57165944E12,
            "value_as_string" : "2019-10-21T12:04:00.000Z"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: HI J!! Thanks, I will try to apply it in KIbana and answer you asap :D, thanks a lot

Comment: How can i test it in Kibana?

Comment: do you mean visualization or in developer tools. In developer tools(kibana) , you can run it and check the output(json format)

Comment: I test it in developer tools, How can i traslate this to a visualization

Comment: Give me some time , will check and get back. i have never tried visualzation before

Comment: There is no option of bucket_selector in kibana visualization , there is open PR for it https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/17544.  I am not aware of any other way to achieve above

Comment: may be you can raise another question regarding visualization, someone might know a way for it

Comment: I will do it, I will try to read something about this in https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/mark.html#mark-def

Comment: I did it on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58498739/kibana-visualization-get-top-hit-with-filter thanks a lot for your help Jaspreet

Comment: glad could be of help