# Get top hit with filter in Kibana visualization

Tags: kibana-7

I will try to explain my issue,

I have this Index

ST   ID   time
0     1      12:04
1     1     12:00
0     2     12:02
1     2     11:58
0     2     11:22
1     3     12:33
0     3     12:20

In Kibana, I'm trying to get a table with the top hit from ID when ST = 0 to have results as

ST    ID    time
0     1      12:04
0     2     12:02

As you could see ID = 3 has top hit with ST = 1, so it shouldn't appear in the table

Could someone help me with this?

BR

BR

Comment: What exactly constitutes a top hit? Why not show the last row? It also has ST=0

Comment: Hi K, top hit is the last doc indexed from each ID, the last row for ID = 3 is ST = 1 so I need all last rows when them has ST = 0. ID = 3 shouldn't appear in the table or graph